# Subscribe mt queue to autofac module

Tags: autofac, masstransit

I'm trying to setup a single service that is broken into several logical services. Because they are logical services, they each get there own queue. Each logical service is a module in autofac.

The setup looks vaguely like:

```
sbc.ReceiveEndpoint(host, "service1", ep => {
  ep.LoadFrom(c.Resolve<ILifetimeScope>())
});
sbc.ReceiveEndpoint(host, "service2", ep => {
  ep.LoadFrom(c.Resolve<ILifetimeScope>())
});
```

But I think this would cause every consumer to be subscribed on every queue.

Is there a built in way I can get autofac to only register consumers from a specific module or would I have to write my own adapter?

Comment: I'll have the example of using RapidTransit for this updated at some point, but we typically create nested lifetime scopes for each logical service, and only register the consumers in the nested scope, making LoadFrom function as expected.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that. It might be a bit nice than using meta data/modules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to write your own adapter. It's not a lot of work. Make sure you resolve the consumers from the container as the concrete class, and not as implementation of `Consumes`.

Comment: Thanks, your right, it isn't a lot of work, especially when you have the existing OSS code to use as a guide.